# Работа iOS (Swift4) приложения только с одним Wi-Fi

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, wifi

Суть вопроса в следующем.
Как организовать работу приложения под iOS на Swift4, для работы только с одной определенной Wi-Fi сетью? 
Ну на пример, на работе с Wi-Fi приложение работает, а дома нет, ну или на оборот.
Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 2):

```
import SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork


func printWiFiSsid() {
    if let interfaces = CNCopySupportedInterfaces() as NSArray? {
        for interface in interfaces {
            if let interfaceInfo = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(interface as! CFString) as NSDictionary? {
                print(interfaceInfo)
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

И добавьте доступ к WiFi информации в настройках проекта:
[image: Access WiFi information]

Comment: Уточню на всякий случай, где лучше реализовать данную функцию? Создать для нее отдельный файл ? И я так понимаю надо подключить - import: SystemConfiguration.CaptiveNetwork

Comment: @AlexxxBill Да, действительно надо подключить. Я добавлю в ответ.
Если приложение не совсем маленькое, надо создавать отдельный файл. Если используется несколько подобных функций - то их лучше выделить в отдельный класс.

Comment: Благодарю за ответ! Буду пробовать.